# Rails 3: Twitter-Bootstrap Tooltips Refuse to Work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, popover

This is driving me absolutely bonkers, and it seems like such a simple thing to implement. I can't get tooltips (or, for that matter, popovers) to work. I have the **'twitter-bootstrap-rails' gem** installed, and I generated the appropriate .js and .css files.

I don't think it's a JQuery issue because I have other JQuery functionality on my site that works perfectly.

Here's some relevant code.

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-tooltip
//= require bootstrap-popover
//= require prototype
//= require prototype_ujs
//= require effects
//= require dragdrop
//= require controls
//= require_tree .
$('a').tooltip();
```

**application.css**

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= reqire_twitter/bootstrap
```

**Code I'd like to get to work for tooltips**

```
<a href="#" title="test" rel="tooltip" id="test-url">test</a>
```

The above code, when hovered over, just shows Chrome's normal tooltip. I'm getting the same behavior in Safari, so I doubt it's browser-specific.

Comment: I had a problem like that but don't remember exactrly what I did.

Try $("a[rel=tooltip]").tooltip(); and add the rel to your link tag.

Comment: That didn't change things, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was two-fold.

1. Change the `$` in the code to `jQuery`. This got rid of the "Object # has no method 'ready'" error.
2. I had a bootstrap.js.coffee file that had irrelevant code. When I deleted the file, everything began working again. This got rid of the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'tooltip' of null" error.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using Rails 3.2.7, adding Bootstrap manually. Everything works just fine.

**application.css**

```
*= require style
*= require bootstrap.min
*= require bootstrap-responsive.min
*= require_tree .
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').tooltip();
});
//= require_tree .
```

and **layout/application.html.erb**

```
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag("application", :media => "all") %>
</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
  <!-- scripts concatenated and minified via build script -->
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <!-- end scripts -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your application.js code will be executed before your web page is fully loaded into the browser, so your line of code will not find any element prior to the page load.

You will need to execute when the DOM is fully loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a').tooltip();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. Unfortunately, this didn't fix the issue. Do you have any other hypotheses?

Comment: Do you have any JS errors? Ensure that all the included JS files from bootstrap are loaded correctly in your browser.  You can use Firebug, or Chrome dev tools to help you out.

Comment: My files are loading correctly, but jQuery is throwing a TypeError and telling me that "Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'."

Comment: ready() is a function in jQuery which is standard for executing code once the DOM is fully loaded.  If you are getting no method error then jQuery is not being loaded correctly, or being loaded after this code is getting executed.  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. While you didn't feed me an answer, you led me in the right direction, and I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

After much fighting, in order to get it working properly with Rails 3.2 I had to do the following:

1. in application.js:

   > //= require bootstrap
2. in the view template where I want the tooltip, include the rel='tooltip' attribute:

   > = link_to "Link text", title: 'Click to reveal tracks', 'data-placement' => 'top', rel: :tooltip

or if you're not using HAML:

```
<a href="#" data-placement="top" rel="tooltip" title="Click to reveal tracks">Link text</a>
```

1. in any of the coffeescript files (I created a new one) put this:

   > jQuery ->
   >       $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip()

This works, though the styling for the tooltips are not working, I can't figure out why, but the javascript seems to be working at least.

Hopefully this will help someome else.

As someone commented already, bootstrap-sass includes a coffeescript file which has this in it:

```
jQuery ->
  $("a[rel=popover]").popover()
  $(".tooltip").tooltip()
  $("a[rel=tooltip]").tooltip()
```

If you call this file there is no need to include the other coffeescript file above since this one does the same thing. In my case I already have `bootstrap.js` called from `application.js` so this one wasn't called (I removed require_tree so I can call the files I want in the order I want).